# How to control several same UIViews in one UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I’m try? iphone app. There is one ViewController which contains three same UIViews. UIViews are inherit from the one custom uiview class which i made in xib file and connect to ViewController. View contains a switch. How ViewController should recognize which views switch tapped user?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? I don't see what you want

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Let's answer the key question in your post:

> How can the ViewController recognize which views switch tapped user?

There are multiple ways for you or your controller know what view is what, which view did this or that, etc...

1. Assign **Tag** to a view. e.g. `self.myView1.tag = 1` .
2. Assign specific class to a view.

From there you'll be able to make your all similar views distinguishable.

Comment: Thank you for rapid answer! I thought about tags, but read some topics where everybody told that it is bad idea to use tags. So i wonder if there a “right” way to do it?

Comment: WHAT?! No! There's a reason why Apple made it available to the developers. But I guess you could say to each their own. I assume they say it's bad if you only use it "too much".

Comment: Ok, thank you! I used tags with multiply pickerViews and it worked fine, so will do here.

Comment: Sure! Good luck!